# Chrome bug not rendering Google Fonts [NOT PROTOCOL ISSUE]

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-devtools, google-font-api, google-fonts

Switched to a free SSL WebHosting (000webhost) and now Google Fonts are not rendering, searched and tried a lot of things, the CSS code to repaint the text does not work, neither the JS, I tried linking the font URL with https: and without protocol (//), nothing happens.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It happens only in Chrome, in Opera and Firefox renders okay.

Curious fact: When I open console with F12 and press CTRL + F5, the google font render okay, but only when I open console and reload, when I enter the site normally it does not render. So crazy.

Here's what the console throws me:

```
The FetchEvent for "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/newscycle/v14/9Xe8dq6pQDsPyVH2D3tMQvk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "same link" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle&subset=latin,latin-ext" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

The FetchEvent for "same link" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors
2undefined 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Was a local problem, entered in:
chrome://serviceworker-internals/

and deleting service workers related to my site and worked, this would be terrible if happened in production mode.